# Search fragment ID from activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have tried out most solutions in Stack Overflow but still unable to search the fragment id as I needed to. I'm trying to `setBackgroundResource` to my image button in my activity under `onCreate` but facing the null reference object when I compile it. Would like to know how to call the id in fragment from an activity, when I search for my `imagebutton` id and runs it, it always come back to null references object.

I have tried:

1) `getView()`

2) `RootView()`

3)

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment liBrary = getSupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentById(R.id.imgbtn1);
   imgBtn1 = (ImageButton) Library.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1);
   imgBtn1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);
```

4)

```
Fragment liBrary = getSupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentById(R.id.imgbtn1);
   imgBtn1 = (ImageButton) Library.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1);
   imgBtn1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);
```

-Edited-
Also just to provide a clearer picture on how I set up my fragment:
**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class Homescreen extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

  @Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homescreen);

  android.app.Fragment library = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.libraryMain);

     (library.getView().findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1)).setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);

}
```

**Fragmentclass.java**

```
public class Library extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    LinearLayout libraryLL = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.library,
            container, false);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Please use camel case on variable for the love of code :) . BTW you are calling `getActivity()` again.

Comment: apologise its an typo error! it started from getSupportFragmentManager

Answer (score 0):

You would have given a id for fragment while creation of fragment in xml which will act as a cointainer.

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.yourfragment"
            android:id="@+id/test_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    android.support.v4.app.Fragment Library = getSupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentById(R.id.test_fragment);
   imgbtn1 = (ImageButton) Library.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1);
   imgbtn1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);
```

Comment: you are using image button as fragment id that will not work.

Comment: One more point do not take the reference of image of fragment and activity and set background for that it will return null because onCreate of fragment are not called when you are trying to set background.

Comment: Thank you for answering but i got the error 
       Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getActivity()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

**Make a method inside your Fragment**

Inside your **`Fragment`** class, make a new `public` method e.g:

```
public void setFragmentBackground(Drawable mipmap) {

}
```

Inside this add `View fragmentView = getView()`
Depending on what your Fragment's XML layout is it would be best to cast it to that.

Then add another line to it:

```
fragmentView.setBackground(mipmap);
```

Then in your activity call this:

```
(theFragment).setFragmentBackground(getDrawable(R.mipmap.exercise));
```

theFragment being the fragment you want to change.

**N.B**

**I had a similar problem, make sure you don't call the method inside your activity's `onCreate()` method... the Fragment doesn't get enough time to be created and thus you can't call the method because the Fragment is a null object.** Instead, call the method inside the Fragment but this way:

```
LinearLayout libraryLL = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.library, null);
libraryLL.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);
```

Comment: Please look at my answer, it should solve your problem

Comment: Hi BlazeDev, I still getting errors and now unable to call inflater.

Comment: And the XML please.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your fragment dynamically from activity like so:

```
YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, yourFragment, YOUR_TAG)
            .commit();
```

Then you can define method in your fragment like so:

```
public void setButtonBackground()
{
    ImageButton imgbtn1 = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1);
    imgbtn1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);
}
```

And call it from activity:

```
yourFragment.setButtonBackground();
```

Upd.:
if you add your static fragments, you should use this:
From Activity:

```
Fragment library = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.test_fragment);
  ((ImageButton) library.getView().findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1)).setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.exercise);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I didn't add my fragments dynamically from activities
I extended my 4 classes all to fragments instead

Comment: Thank you but still getting error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please, post xml file your activity, where you add this fragment, and your fragment xml too.

Comment: I didn't define my fragment in xml on either side

Comment: But you should do it. There are two ways to add fragment: static (define it in activity's xml) or dynamic (define a container in activity's xml file and add fragment programmatically to this container in your activity). More you can see there: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html. I recommend you learn 104,105,106 lessons for understanding fragments.

Comment: Thank you Mr Hetfieldan, I went to the site you recommend but apparently when i click english language it does not provide me the lesson 104-106.

Comment: Sure, my mistake. You can read about fragments here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html.